# Can't disable airplane mode due to hard blocked Wireless LAN

Tags: networking, wireless, asus

I run Linux on an ASUS N61JQ Notebook, and cannot use my WiFi network. Airplane Mode is on, and the option to disable it is greyed out.

When I run *rfkill list* I can see that "phy0: Wireless LAN" has these settings:

- Soft blocked: no
- Hard blocked: yes

On the ASUS Notebook I should supposedly be able to disable the hard block by using *Fn+F2*. However for some reason, this only toggles the soft block.

I've tried *rfkill unblock all*, but it doesn't have an effect.

I've also tried updating my BIOS, and restoring default settings, but that doesn't work either.

Can you think of anything else to try?

UPDATE:

I tried Mr chili555's suggestion of running this code:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf"
```

It didn't solve my problem. Despite the file being created successfully in the correct directory (+ reboot), the driver "asus_nb_wmi" isn't listed when I run this code:

```
lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus
```

More information:

```
root@eiricur:~# rfkill list
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: yes
 root@eiricur:~# lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
     Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE785 / AW-NE785H 802.11bgn Wireless Full or Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1a3b:1089]
     Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 root@eiricur:~# lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus
 ath9k                  94208  0
 ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
 ath9k_hw              446464  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
 ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
 mac80211              626688  1 ath9k
 cfg80211              540672  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
 asus_laptop            32768  0
 sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_laptop
 rfkill                 24576  6 cfg80211,asus_laptop,bluetooth
 input_polldev          16384  1 asus_laptop
 video                  36864  1 asus_laptop
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve my problem. I've updated the OP.

Comment: First try to completely kill `asus_nb_wmi` by `sudo modprbe -r asus_nb_wmi`. If that helps, then you can try other wapf, like `wapf=4`.

Comment: What kernel version `uname -a`

Comment: @Pilot6 for some reason "asus_nb_wmi" isn't loaded, despite having been created it in the correct directory using the command detailed above, and rebooting. Trying to kill it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Linux eiricur 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux